# Permutation group - Groups and Symmetries

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many elements of order $k$ are in $S_n$ for $k<n$.

$S_n$ is the permutation group of order $n$.

Attempt: I thought it's just the number of ways you can pick $k$ objects out of $n$ objects so it's $n$ choose $k$. Is this right? I think the answer should not exceed the order of $S_n$ which is $n!$ so this makes sense to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly, since $(123)(45) $ has order $6 $ but only involves $5 $ elements. Another example is $(12)(34) $ which has order $2 $ but involves $4 $ elements.

Comment: You've only counted permutations that consist of a single cycle.

Comment: This is actually a tricky question. It is discussed in [Number of permutations of order k](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006752/number-of-permutations-of-order-k).  Note that the restriction $k<n$ is nontrivial; for example, $S_5$ contains elements of order 6 and $S_8$ contains elements of orders 12 and 15, but not 13 or 14.

Answer (score 1):

Your method gives you a *lower bound* on the number of elements of order $k$ in $S_n$, where $1 < k \leq n$. As has been pointed out, this counts elements that are a single cycle, in cycle notation.

So, in $S_6$, the permutation $\pi = (123)(456)$ is an element of order 3, but it won't have been counted by the above argument. Additionally, permutations $(1234)$ and $(1243)$ are distinct, but would presumably have lumped together, in your combinatorial argument.